# Understanding RegEx and the Matcher.find() method

Tags: java, regex

I can't understand what is wrong with this code and what the `find()` method does:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab");
m.find(); // if i comment this the code with throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
String output = String.format("found the text \"%s\" beginning at index %d and end at index %d ",m.group() ,m.start() , m.end());
System.out.println(output);
```

I think that `find()` method's job is to search for a pattern, and return the match in the string we are searching. Can anyone explain me why I get an error if I comment out the `m.find()` method call?

Comment: check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Comment: [Your code](http://ideone.com/VtCbLY) is working.

Comment: i saw this earlier ... but the problem is about this error ... the find() method return true or false in different circumstance ... why i get this error ?

Comment: @stribizhev  i know my code is working :) ... but commenting m.find() will cause an no match available error

Comment: Why do you want to comment out `find()`? It means you declare a regex pattern, get everything ready, but do not "press START button".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` does exactly what it is supposed to do. From [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--)

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.

You cannot call `group()` unless you call `find()` because you will not have found a match. `find()` is used to find the matching group(s) which can then be accessed using `group()`

Answer (score 1):

as @TheLostMind said u can't call group unless you call find().

the correct way of using `find()` is to use it in a loop:

```
while(m.find()){ //ends when it can't find anything else that matches
   String output = String.format("found the text \"%s\" beginning at index %d and end at index %d ",m.group() ,m.start() , m.end());
   System.out.println(output); 
}
```